# Looking for an efficient way to remove all occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have many text files (10,000,000) and I want to remove all tokens which are started with */m/* from them. I wrote the following code but I am looking for faster code because I tokenize string then join tokens again.

```
import nltk
def removeMId(str):
words=[]
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(str)
i=0
for tkn in tokens:
    if not tkn.startswith('/m/'):
       words.append(tkn)
       i+=1
return ' '.join(words)
```

All removal tokens follow this `pattern=r''' /\m+(?:[-'/]\w+)*'''`

This is an example of input:

> the manuscript handling fee (checks must be in **/m/09c7w0**  dollars, drawn on a **/m/09c7w0**  bank, MICR encoded at the bottom of the check, and payable to ASPET). **/m/01kqjn**  **/m/021b7r**  and **/m/01w6dw**  credit cards are also accepted.

Comment: Could you provide examples of tokens you want to remove?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I add an example in my question

Comment: The fastest way will be using simple `string.replace()` (looking at your example, not necessarily a general solution): `your_string.replace(" /m/", " ")` Of course, if you need to handle special cases only then you may need to 'tokenize' your string and comb it more thoroughly.

Comment: in this case why don't you use re.sub before tokenizing since you already have the pattern?

Comment: Since you have a lot of files, you can also use a combination of find and sed, that is probably faster than a python script.

Comment: As Casimir has already said, the fastest way is to use sed. Your use case is so simple that you can do it with a single command line!

Comment: @zwer replace is just remove **/m/** part of token. It does not work.\

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte could you explain more about find and sed?

Comment: @user3092781 - sorry, I misunderstood what you want, check the answer bellow...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll bite - the straight-forward approach is to do it with regex:

```
import re

TOKEN_REMOVER = re.compile(r"/m+[-'/]\w+\s?")

def removeMId(source):
    return TOKEN_REMOVER.sub("", source)
```

It ought to be significantly faster than your example. That being said, Python is not designed to break speed/efficiency records so if all you need is one-time file modification you might want to look into dedicated compiled tools for the exact same task.

Comment: what is different between efficiency of your suggestion and this line `re.sub(r''' /\m+(?:[-'/]\w+)*''',"",source)`. Also could you explain more about **dedicated compiled tools**

Comment: This compiles the regex so you don't have to rebuild the engine on each call plus it doesn't use non-capturing lookahead groups for no reason. And I've added optional search for space (including new lines and such) at the end instead of hard-coded single space in front, which sounds more logical, but that's just aesthetics.

Comment: As for compiled tools, `sed` is quite good for replacing substrings in files. For example, `sed -r -i 's/\/m+[-'/]\w+\s?//g' your_file.ext` ought to do it in a fraction of time Python needs (not to mention that it can execute over your 10.000.000 files just by setting a file mask at the end).